# OpenERP Report over multiple purchase orders using openoffice / libreoffice

Tags: reporting, odoo

I was able to add a report record for object purchase.order. It shows up when I select and open a specific PO.

How do I print a report over multiple purchase orders, or multiple stock moves, or multiple sales orders etc.?

What do I specify in "object" (model) for the report record and where would this print menu show up?

(I am using aeroo reports engine and I was able to specify a

```
  <for each..> ... </for>
```

loop but it only prints one record (which is the currently selected PO).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

at report template level you have two variables `o` and `objects`. the 1st one is present if you have only one item. the second one should be always available and must contains all the selected objects (or the objects that has been filtered  trough a custom parser).

TIP: when you have doubt on how to do things... just look at how other modules do.

Answer (score 0):

I. Create your report as it was intended for one object only.

`<for each="o in objects"></for>` as you define

II. On your OpenERP, go to Settings->Customization->Aeroo Reports->Reports and open the report you've previously created. On the report, click the Advanced tab and enable Process separately then save.

Hope this help to you.

Regard,